# use jquery attribute with variable in value place

Tags: jquery

```
<a href="/JqueryTest/Delete/23" class="Delete-item">Delete</a>
```

if i use this JQuery code :

```
$('.Delete-item[href="/JqueryTest/Delete/23"]')
```

It work fine , but if i replace Value with my variable :

```
var MyVar= "/JqueryTest/Delete/23";
$('.Delete-item[href=MyVar]')
```

I have on error syntaxe, any help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to concatenate the string in this way..

```
var MyVar= "/JqueryTest/Delete/23";
$('.Delete-item[href="' + MyVar + '"]');
```

Comment: so you can accept the answer and upVote it too..if it helps you.. :)

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
var MyVar= "/JqueryTest/Delete/23";
$('.Delete-item[href="' + MyVar + '"]');
```

Concatenate the variable into the string

Comment: is `"` necessary here on `"' + MyVar + '"` ?

Comment: Yup, attributes need to be quoted

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   var MyVar= "/JqueryTest/Delete/23";
    $('.Delete-item[href="'+MyVar+'"]')
```

Comment: You forgot the `"` around the attribute

Answer (score 0):

`$('.Delete-item[href=' + MyVar + ']')`

Comment: You forgot the `"` around the attribute

Answer (score 0):

myVar in [href=myVar] is a part of a string not a variable. So you need to say
`$('.Delete-item[href="' + MyVar + '"]')`